# TagLib: could not open file

Tags: c++, audio, boost, metadata, taglib

I m trying to write a simple program to find how TagLib (http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html) works . The program works fine with the comments in the code. But when i change the code I m getting these error which I m not able to resolve. 
Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<QString>
//#include "Helper.h"
#include "../../player/Util.h"
#include <taglib/tag.h>
#include <taglib/taglib.h>
#include <taglib/fileref.h>
#include <QString>


#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using std::string;
struct MetaData{

    string filepath, artist, album, title;
    signed int year, track_num, length_ms, bitrate;
};

//MetaData getMetaDataOfFile(QString file)
MetaData getMetaDataOfFile(string file)
{
    MetaData md;
    //TagLib::FileRef f(TagLib::FileName(file.toUtf8())); 
    const char * filename = file.c_str();
    std::cout<< filename;
    TagLib::FileRef f(TagLib::FileName(filename)); 

    //md.filepath = file.toStdString();
    md.filepath = file;

    //boost::filesystem::path filePath(file.toStdString());
    boost::filesystem::path filePath(file);
    md.title = filePath.stem().string();

    if(f.isNull()) return md;
    if(!f.tag()) return md;
    if(f.tag()->isEmpty()) return md;

    string artist = f.tag()->artist().to8Bit(true);
    string album = f.tag()->album().to8Bit(true);
    string title = f.tag()->title().to8Bit(true);
    uint year = f.tag()->year();
    uint track = f.tag()->track();
    int bitrate = f.audioProperties()->bitrate() * 1000;
    int length = f.audioProperties()->length();

    md.album = cnvrtString2FirstUpper(album);
    md.artist = cnvrtString2FirstUpper(artist);
    md.title = cnvrtString2FirstUpper(title);
    //md.filepath = file.toStdString();
    md.filepath = file;
    md.length_ms = length * 1000;
    md.year = year;
    md.track_num = track;
    md.bitrate = bitrate;

    if(md.title.length()==0)
    {

    //boost::filesystem::path filePath(file.toStdString());
    boost::filesystem::path filePath(file);
    md.title = filePath.stem().string();
    }

    return md;
}






int main()
{
    using namespace std;



    //QString file("/home/vickey/Downloads/song1.mp3");
    string file("/home/vickey/Downloads/song1.mp3");
    MetaData md = getMetaDataOfFile(file);

    return 0;

}
```

on Compiling I get this error

```
 g++ getmd.cpp -o getmd -I /usr/include/qt4/ -I /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/ -ltag -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lQtCore -g
getmd.cpp: In function ‘MetaData getMetaDataOfFile(std::string)’:
getmd.cpp:36:10: error: request for member ‘isNull’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
getmd.cpp:37:11: error: request for member ‘tag’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
getmd.cpp:38:10: error: request for member ‘tag’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
getmd.cpp:40:23: error: request for member ‘tag’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
getmd.cpp:41:22: error: request for member ‘tag’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
getmd.cpp:42:22: error: request for member ‘tag’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
getmd.cpp:43:19: error: request for member ‘tag’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
g    etmd.cpp:44:20: error: request for member ‘tag’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
getmd.cpp:45:21: error: request for member ‘audioProperties’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
getmd.cpp:46:20: error: request for member ‘audioProperties’ in ‘f’, which is of non-class type ‘TagLib::FileRef(TagLib::FileName) {aka TagLib::FileRef(const char*)}’
```

Comment: When you change the code to what??

Comment: the comment in the code is the original code . What follows the comment is the changed code.

Comment: Try an extra pair of parentheses around the constructor argument: `TagLib::FileRef f((TagLib::FileName(file.toUtf8())));` This could help resolve a particular ambiguity of the C++ grammar.

Comment: Strange but now it is working with "TagLib::FileRef f(TagLib::FileName(file.c_str()));" . I really dont know what was wrong , but now its working fine :)

Comment: Using `c_str()` to do filename conversion will fail with some encodings (it will compile, but not open the file).  See my answer below for the correct way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

Both versions -- the commented and uncommented -- are wrong.  TagLib, on Unix, expects `const char *` file names.  The best way to get one from a `QString` is with [`QFile::encodeName()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#encodeName).  So what you should have is something like this:

```
TagLib::FileRef f(QFile::encodeName(file).constData());
```

Comment: TagLib::FileRef f(TagLib::FileName(file.toUtf8()));  woks fine where file is a QString. The program right now only supports basic string file name , In future for UTF file name c_str() is not a good solution. I will consider your solution when the need arises

Comment: Again, sorry, but that's incorrect.  The method that I posted is the correct way to convert a `QString` to a `const char *`.  `file.toUtf8()` will *compile*, but it will fail for non-ASCII filenames on file systems that don't use UTF-8 encoding.  For example, if you had a file from Björk on a ISO-8859-1 encoded filesystem, your code would not open it.  Using `QFile::encodeName()` considers the encoding of the underlying filesystem.

Comment: Ugh, can't edit the comment anymore -- I should have that that's the correct way to convert a `QString` to a `const char *` for use in a *filename*; other methods are totally fine in other cases.